# How to write operator= (with move semantic) and shrink_to_fit functions in my vector implementation?

Tags: c++

I have my own vector class:

```
#include<iterator>
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<exception> 

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::size_t;

template <class T> class vector
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const iterator const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    //------------------------------------------
    vector() { create(); }
    explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T{}) { create(n, value); }
    vector(const vector& a) { create(a.begin(), a.end()); }
```

And operators:

```
    vector& operator=(const vector& a)
    {
        if (&a == this)  return *this;
        uncreate();
        create(a.begin(), a.end());
        return *this;
    }

vector& operator=(const vector&& a)
    {
        if (&a == this)  return *this;
        uncreate();

        //NEED TO WRITE SOME CODE HERE

    }
    ~vector() { uncreate(); } //destructor
    size_type size() const { return avail - data; }
    size_type capacity() const { return limit - data; }
```

And private class members:

```
  private:
  iterator data;
  iterator avail;
  iterator limit;

  std::allocator<T> alloc;
//--------------------------------
  void create()
  {
      data = avail = limit = nullptr;
  }
```

And I should write operator = with the move (which I do not know how to write) and copy (which I have done) semantics. Can you help me?

Comment: *I do not know what code should I write after this* – I do not know what code you've written at all. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: The usual implementation of move semantics for a vector-like template is to simply swap all members of the two vectors -- usually the internal array pointer and the array size; and perhaps the maximum array size. Your move operator should consist of either two or three calls to `std::swap`, followed by `return`. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
vector& operator=(vector&& a) noexcept
{
    a.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

void swap(vector& otherVector) noexcept
{
   //swap all member variables here (I took some names that might not be the same, that you use)
   std::swap(otherVector.capacity, capacity);
   std::swap(otherVector.size,   size);
   std::swap(otherVector.buffer,   buffer);
}
```

thats how I would write it (deleting is not needed,because it's swapped and so it will be deleted when the other vector goes out of scope)

obviously when you do not want a swap function you could aswell just put everything the swap function does into the move assignment operator ;)

Comment: but 'swap': is not a member of 'vector<int>'

Comment: ok I added a swap function (yes the variables I swap might not be the same you use, but i do not know your exact implementation from what you have posted)